# Scroll anchor not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I scroll and the anchor touches the top of the window, the background color of the box is supposed to change but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/6p2pnnq4/1/

```
    var scrollFn = function() {
  var targetOffset = $(this).find(".anchor-point")[0].offsetTop;
  console.log('Scrolling...');

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > targetOffset) {
    $(this).find(".footer_wrap").addClass("topper");

  } else {
    $(this).find(".footer_wrap").removeClass("topper");
  }
};

$(window).scroll(scrollFn);
```

Comment: You have a console, it's generally opened by hitting F12, and in it you can actually see what's wrong with your code. It's the `$(this).find()` line that doesn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the

```
$(this).find
```

It is useless, try the following:

```
var targetOffset = $('#footer_wrap').offset().top,
$window = $(window);
$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= targetOffset ) {
        $("#footer_wrap").addClass("topper");
    }else{
        $("#footer_wrap").removeClass("topper");
    }
});
```

And The CSS

```
#footer_wrap {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 130vmax;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#footer_wrap.topper {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Then when #footer_wrap is at the top it will change the background.

Check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/077aeerm/)